# Debugging React Hooks Rerender issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a very simple hook that looks like this:

```
export const QuickViewCell = props => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)

  const handleMouseEvent = () => {
    console.log('calling')
    setHover(!hover)
  }

  console.log('hoverState', hover)

  return (
    <Box onMouseEnter={handleMouseEvent} onMouseLeave={handleMouseEvent}>
      <Text size="small">
        {String(props.data.name)} this is my custom cell and it is amazing
      </Text>
    </Box>
  )
```

It works when placed in one part of the project, but doesn't when placed in another. Meaning, the `handleMouseEvent` function is always being called, but the component isn't re-rendering with the new state. React and React-Dom are at 16.8.1. I'm not getting any errors. I'm not sure where to look for the bug.

If I change it to a class component using `setState`, it works fine, which makes me think I've got an incompatibility issue somewhere, but without an error message, not sure where to look. Or I'm missing something more obvious :)

Anyone experience something like this? Is there a way to determine if there is an incompatibility with another package?

Comment: Could you include the piece of code where this works, and also include the code where this doesn't work?

Comment: Please show the sequence of console logs from the two cases.

Comment: In the case that works, I get both 'calling' and 'hoverState' on every mouse leave/enter. In the other case, I get only 'calling' but not the new 'hoverState' log. The code for this component is identical in both cases, it's mainly the packages that are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following wording in your question:

> It works when placed in one part of the project, but doesn't when
>   placed in another.

I assumed that the two places were part of the same build (i.e. same `package.json`). If that was the case, it seemed unlikely that it was an incompatibility issue. But the following recent comment:

> The code for this component is identical in both cases, it's mainly
>   the packages that are different.

makes it sound like the two cases are part of separate builds. If this is true, then I think the hook-incompatibility theory is reasonable, though I'm not entirely convinced because I would expect a message in the console in that case (but I suspect there are some variations on the multiple-react-copies issue that wouldn't cause a message in the console).

The following page from the documentation has instructions on troubleshooting this:

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react

On that page you'll find the below instructions for determining whether you have multiple versions of react in play.

> You can run `npm ls react-dom` or `npm ls react-native` in your
>   application folder to check which version you’re using. If you find
>   more than one of them, this might also create problems (more on that
>   below).

And then further down:

> If you use Node for package management, you can run this check in your
>   project folder:
>
> `npm ls react`

If this doesn't show any surprises (i.e. just shows one copy of 16.8.1 for both react and react-dom), then I would move forward with assuming there is something other than an incompatibility going on and would want to see the code that uses `QuickViewCell` in the problem case.

On a tangential note regarding jayarjo's recommendation to use the "functional update" syntax, I think the more appropriate way to update this `hover` state in order to more easily know that it is correct/robust would be to explicitly pass the boolean rather than doing a toggle of whatever the state currently is.

For example:

```
export const QuickViewCell = props => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Box onMouseEnter={()=>setHover(true)} onMouseLeave={()=>setHover(false)}>
      <Text size="small">
        {String(props.data.name)} this is my custom cell and it is amazing
      </Text>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This makes it easier to be confident that you won't accidentally get in a state where hover is stuck as the opposite of what it should be.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Some library must have React installed as a dependency instead of peer dependency. The above link shows how to confirm that there are duplicate react versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When previous state is used to calculated next one, it is recommended to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

So instead of `setHover(!hover)` try `setHover(hover => !hover)`. That should do.

Comment: This may still be a good idea, but, aside from edge-case timing scenarios, it shouldn’t be necessary since a re-render will cause a new `handleMouseEvent` to be used that closes over the new `hover` value.

Comment: Doesn't this solve the actual problem for you though?

Comment: I agree with Ryan, this might be a good idea in general, but this doesn't solve the problem. It is almost most certainly an incompatibility with something, i.e. some library isn't working with React hooks. I just don't have a way to find it.